# splitting text with javascript match

Tags: javascript, regex

for below code

```
var str = "I left the United States with my eyes full of tears! I knew I would miss my American friends very much.All the best to you";
var re = new RegExp("[^\.\?!]*(?:[\.\?!]+|\s$)", "g");
var myArray = str.match(re);
```

and This is what I am getting as a result

```
myArray[0] = "I left the United States with my eyes full of tears!"
myArray[1] = " I knew I would miss my American friends very much."
```

I want to add one more condition to regex such that the text will break only if there is a 
space after the the punctuation mark (? or . or !)

I do it do that  so the result for above case is

```
myArray[0] = "I left the United States with my eyes full of tears!"
myArray[1] = " I knew I would miss my American friends very much.All the best to you "
myArray[2] = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.+?([!?.](?= |$)|$)
```

should work.

It will match any sequence of characters that are either

- followed by a punctuation sign that is itself followed by a space or end-of-string, or
- followed by the end of the string.

By using the reluctant quantifier `+?`, it finds the shortest possible sequences (=single sentences).

In JavaScript:

```
result = subject.match(/.+?([!?.](?= |$)|$)/g);
```

EDIT:

In order to avoid the regex splitting on "space/single letter or multidigit number/dot", you can use:

```
result = subject.match(/( \d+\.| [^\W\d_]\.|.)+?([!?.](?= |$)|$)/g);
```

This will split

> I left the United States with my eyes
>   full of tears! 23. I knew I would miss
>   my American friends very much. I. All
>   the best to you.

into

```
I left the United States with my eyes full of tears!
 23. I knew I would miss my American friends very much.
 I. All the best to you.
```

What it does is instead of simply matching any character until it finds a dot is:

- First try to match a space, a number, and a dot.
- If that fails, try to match a space, a letter, and a dot.
- If that fails, match any character.

That way, the dot after a number/letter has already been matched and will not be matched as the delimiting punctuation character that follows next in the regex.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the string to break in statements if the character is like " S." "space" followed by "single character or multidigit number" followed by a "." ? Actually I want to understand how we can achieve this so that I can add more such cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying to understand the expression.

Answer (score 1):

var str = "I left the United States with my eyes full of tears! I knew I would miss my American friends very much.All the best to you";

```
var re =/[^\.\?!]+[\.?!]( +|[^\.\?!]+)/g;
var myArray = str.match(re);
myArray.join('\n')

/*  returned value: (String)
I left the United States with my eyes full of tears! 
I knew I would miss my American friends very much.All the best to you
*/
```